# Unzip iterator of references to tuples into two collections of references

Tags: reference, iterator, rust, tuples, ownership

I have an `Iterator<Item = &(T, U)>` over a slice `&[(T, U)]`. I'd like to unzip this iterator into its components (i.e. obtain `(Vec<&T>, Vec<&U>)`).

Rust provides unzip functionality through the `.unzip()` method on `Interator`:

```
points.iter().unzip()
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as-is because `.unzip()` expects the type of the iterator's item to be a tuple; mine is a reference to a tuple.

To fix this, I tried to write a function which converts between a reference to a tuple and a tuple of references:

```
fn distribute_ref<'a, T, U>(x: &'a (T, U)) -> (&'a T, &'a U) {
    (&x.0, &x.1)
}
```

I can then `map` over the resulting iterator to get something `.unzip()` can handle:

```
points.iter().map(distribute_ref).unzip()
```

This works now, but I this feels a bit strange. In particular, `distribute_ref` seems like a fairly simple operation that would be provided by the Rust standard library. I'm guessing it either is and I can't find it, or I'm not approaching this the right way.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a better way to do this?

"Better" is a bit subjective. You can make your function shorter:

```
fn distribute_ref<T, U>(x: &(T, U)) -> (&T, &U) {
    (&x.0, &x.1)
}
```

[Lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision) allows to omit lifetime annotations in this case.

You can use a closure to do the same thing:

```
points.iter().map(|&(ref a, ref b)| (a, b)).unzip()
```

Depending on the task it can be sufficient to clone the data. Especially in this case, as reference to `u8` takes 4 or 8 times more space than `u8` itself.

```
points().iter().cloned().unzip()
```